# Trying to understand C#, WPF and User Input between functions

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, function

I am new here as well as to C#. I'm trying to learn it better and as a basic programming challenge for myself, I'm trying to understand how to move or return certain values from user input/text boxes after being submitted to a table that is displayed in a list.

Here is my "challenge" I'm trying to create a simple program that has 2 text boxes one for a name of the new value to a list (not an array I've learned that the hard way) and one for a name of a searched value in a said list. Submit button for each of those text boxes with a message stating either "Value Added" when it was added, or "Found" "Doesn't Exist" for the search button. Then on a side of said boxes and buttons I actually want to display my list with a scrollable 2 column window / box, First column as position in a table like value in which its at and then the actual name of the said value that was added. (Oh an also a clear button for the list itself)

So here is what I've gathered so far. I understand I have to transform all input into a string and then push it to the list. I know how to display the `MessageBox.Show("")` however I don't know how to code conditions to it. I would try a simple `if ()` but I would first need to be able to program a working search function which requires pushing and pulling data from the list. I know JavaScript has `array.push` and `array.indexof` which makes finding and pushing things into an array rather simple, but to my knowledge, C# does not have that function.

I am new to this so any tips on a material to read that would help me learn C# or any tips on how to make this work properly will be appreciated. My biggest struggle is to return a value from the said text box into another `private void` and using it in my `var`, in other words pushing the product of a function into another function (like in the example below pushing the `Add_Text.Text` into the `var names = new List<string>();` which is in another void above it. Anyway here is my coding or failed attempt at making this somewhat "work".

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace ArrayApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // ARRAY CODING / LIST CODING

        public class Values
        {
            public string Position { get; set; } = string.Empty;

            public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        }

        public void App()
        {
            var names = new List<string>();

        }

        // BUTTON CLICKS / BUTTON ACTION CODING

        private void Add_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            List_Box.Content = Add_Text.Text;
            MessageBox.Show("Value Added");
            Add_Text.Clear();
        }

        private void Search_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        // TEXT BOXES / WHAT BUTTON ACTUALLY INPUTS INTO OUR DISPLAY

        private void Add_Text_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Search_Text_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        // DISPLAY - List_Box not added yet

    }
 }
```

Comment: Use List<Values> as the collection to hold your data. Then you can use .Conatins() to search an item and .Add() to add new item to the list.

Comment: _I understand I have to transform all input into a string_ - `Add_Text.Text` is a string already, no need to transform. With `List_Box.Content = Add_Text.Text` you are **replacing** listbox content. Btw, there is [List_Box.Items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.items?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_ListBox_Items) property, which have `Add()` method for this.

Comment: Also, as you starting with WPF - you need to understand a basic principles of MVVM, because WPF is all about MVVM. [Here](https://prismlibrary.github.io/) you can read about it.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're looking for but to clarify: a method/function that returns `void` doesn't compose (you can't "push" anything out of it into another function). And the side effects resulting of a call to a void-returning function that happens to satisfy a call to another function isn't composition; it's more or less luck.

Comment: Thank you for the help I think I got a better idea and will read about MVVM. What I meant by pushing out of a function is like the return value of the function be available to another function maybe if I was to code it with another language it would explain it better. Thank you for the tips tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after doing some reading and also your comments helped a lot, I think I got hang of it and got some basic understanding of C# at least how it works logically. This is the "final" version of the AMAZING program I was trying to create. Thanks for the help everyone!

P.S. The comments are for me to learn and reference in the future when I'm learning C# or forget things :)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;


/* QUICK TERMINOLOGY

    List = An Array that constantly adjusts its maximum size

    names = Our actual "database" or table with our values that we've inputted

    List_Box = The display table that is visible on the program itself

    var = Variable... You know...

    "public" or "private" = Those define whether the function is visible to the rest of the program or other "sheets" in the program

    void = Defines whether the return value or the output of a function should be something, void means not specified, 
            if you want string you put string, if you want an integer you put int... etc etc.

*/



namespace ArrayApp
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        /* Private Function for Creating the List which will be a String
        We are using a List instead of an Array as an Array needs 
        a specific amount of indexes so if we have a specific number of data or 
        a maximum amount of data that a user can input then array would be used
        but since we don't know how many indexes we need a list will automatically
        adjust the maximum size of our table to suit our needs. I.e. limitless  */

        private List<string> names;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            names = new List<string>();

        }

        /* Class for our Items in our list this is not referring the list above but...
        the list that it displays as we have a search on demand
        but also allows us to search for specific people in the List (array/table) rather than
        display over 100+ people, if our database was to get to that size.

        Our class function defines what data can be put into our Display List ( List_Box ) 
        Therefore the index can only be an integer and name can only be a string
        more on this later.  */

        class Items
        {
            public int Index { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }

        /* The Add Button Function
        This button takes the content of the TextBox that is right next to it and 
        adds it to our list called "names" but does not update our display, instead
        it shows us a message stating that the value was added to the list.
        If we were using an Array with a limited size, we could use an IF to check
        if there is a space available and output a message saying "Full" or "Failed"  */

        private void Add_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            names.Add(Add_Text.Text); // Adds the value

            Add_Text.Clear(); // Clears the text box

            MessageBox.Show("Value Added"); // Displays a message
        }


        /* Firstly...

         * We have an IF function that checks whether "names" contains the content
                of the search box, so if its a letter "a", it checks if its in our list.
         * It then creates a variable "SearchText" that we can later use that simply
                means that instead of writing the whole code we can just refer to it by our new name
         * Another variable! This one defines our Index in our list, it takes
                our previous variable and looks for it in our list and finds what
                the index number of that value is.
         * Now, since its Search on demand we essentially have two Lists (arrays) now
                that we have the name of the value we looking for in string format,
                we also have our index as integer (defined earlier in class). We need to take that data
                and add it to our display List and for that we have our function.
                Adds new Items to our list using the Items Class and also defines
                what data should be put into each column.
         * It then clears the search text box
         * and shows us that the value has been found.

         We then move to ELSE which is simple really...

            * Didn't find data
            * Clears search text box
            * Displays message that its not been found...  */


        private void Search_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (names.Contains(Search_Text.Text))  // Our If statement
            {
                var SearchText = Search_Text.Text;  // First Variable

                var FindIndex = names.IndexOf(SearchText);  // Second Variable

                List_Box.Items.Add(new Items() { Index = FindIndex, Name = SearchText});  // Adding items to display list

                Search_Text.Clear();  // Clear search text box

                MessageBox.Show("Data Found"); // Display message
            }
            else
            {
                Search_Text.Clear();

                MessageBox.Show("Not Found");
            };
        }

        /* Lastly a simple clear button for our display list.
         * Once a user searches for many values and wants to clear the display list
         * he can do it by hitting a single button.
         * 
         * This button DOES NOT delete anything from our "names" list it only
         * clears the display data meaning that the user can search for more data
         * that has been added already.  */


        private void Clear_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            List_Box.Items.Clear();
        }

        private void Add_Text_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Search_Text_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void ListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

    }
 }
```

[Here is how it looks, simple but you get the idea, I'm learning...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAqiQ.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

Let's walk through this. As you've already mentioned, you need something to store your data. `List` is a good idea since you don't know the size.
Currently, you're creating a `List` of the type `string`, that would work.
There's actually no need for the `Values` class because because you can get the index of an item with a function called `IndexOf` - but later more.

Now, once you show the `MessageBox` when adding an item, you also have to actually add it to your `names` list. In order to do so, declare the `List` in your class and initialize it in your constructor. That way you're able to access if from everywhere in your class.

```
private List<string> names;
public void MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    names = new List<string>();
}
```

Adding items can be done with the `.Add` method, it's pretty straight forward.

```
private void Add_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    List_Box.Content = Add_Text.Text;
    MessageBox.Show("Value Added");

    names.Add(Add_Text.Text); // Adding the content of Add_text.Text

    Add_Text.Clear();
}
```

Searching for an item is pretty easy, too. Just use `Contains` if you want to know whether the item exists or `IndexOf` if you want to have the index as well. Note: `IndexOf` returns `-1` if nothing can be found.

```
private void Search_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(names.Contains( SEARCH_TEXT.TEXT /* or wherever you get your pattern from */ )){
        // found, display this in some way
    } else {
        // not found, display this is some way
    }
}
```

`SEARCH_TEXT.TEXT` contains the pattern you're looking for. I don't know how you named your control, simply replace it.

That's pretty much it.

Comment: This is what I needed! Thank you so much I think I understand it I will apply it now and see how it all works and why it works. Thanks! I didn't know index of is a function in C# hahaha I thought it doesn't exist thank you for the detailed explanation!